# Is there any reason to have 8 on TREEIFY_THRESHOLD in Java Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

From Java 8, the hashMap modified slightly to have balanced tree instead of linkedlist if more than 8 (TREEIFY_THRESHOLD=8) items on same bucket. is there any reason choosing 8?

would it impact the performance in case it is 9?

Comment: A linked list is faster than a tree until *log(N) < N/2*, which happens at *N = 8*.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't java's HashMap just use trees for collision chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030269/why-doesnt-javas-hashmap-just-use-trees-for-collision-chaining#comment96822932_55030269).

Answer (score 3):

The use of a balanced tree instead of a linked-list is a tradeoff. In the case of a list, a linear scan must be performed to perform a lookup in a bucket, while the tree allows for log-time access. When the list is small, the lookup is fast and using a tree doesn't actually provide a benefit while around 8 or so elements the cost of a lookup in the list becomes significant enough that the tree provides a speed-up.

I suspect that the use of a tree is intended for the exceptional case where the key hash is catastrophically broken (e.g. many keys collide); while a linear lookup will cause performance to degrade severely the use of a tree mitigates this 
performance loss somewhat, *if* the keys are directly comparable.

Therefore, the exact threshold of 8 entries may not be terribly significant: the chance of a tree bin is 0.00000006 assuming good key distribution, so tree bins are obviously used very rarely in such a case. When the hash algorithm is failing catastrophically, then the number of keys in the bucket is far greater than 8 anyway.

This comes at a space penalty since the tree-node must include additional references: four references to tree nodes and a boolean *in addition to* the fields of a `LinkedHashMap.Entry` (see [its source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1791)).

From the [comments in the HashMap class source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l174):

> Because TreeNodes are about twice the size of regular nodes, we
>         use them only when bins contain enough nodes to warrant use
>         (see TREEIFY_THRESHOLD). And when they become too small (due to
>         removal or resizing) they are converted back to plain bins.  In
>         usages with well-distributed user hashCodes, tree bins are
>         rarely used.  Ideally, under random hashCodes, the frequency of
>         nodes in bins follows a Poisson distribution
>         (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with a
>         parameter of about 0.5 on average for the default resizing
>         threshold of 0.75, although with a large variance because of
>         resizing granularity. Ignoring variance, the expected
>         occurrences of list size k are (exp(-0.5) * pow(0.5, k) /
>         factorial(k)).